# javascript replace question mark

Tags: javascript, regex

how to make a regex for `?` and `=` in javascript?

I want something from

`http://localhost/search?search=words`

to

`http://localhost/search/search/words`

(?search=) to (/search/)

```
<script>
var ss = "http://localhost/search?search=words".replace("/\?search\=/g", "/search/");
document.write(ss);
</script>
```

BTW: just some prastic, not a htaccss rewrite. Thanks.

Comment: Changing from key-value pairs to single value directory doesn't make sense and can really goof up whatever encoding you've got. Yeah, you said practice, but what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Almost there! `=` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped. In addition, regex strings are not wrapped by quotes. So:

```
"http://localhost/search?search=words".replace(/\?search=/g, "/search/");
```

Comment: +1 for being 120 seconds faster! =) (and, of course, absolutely correct!)

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
str.replace(/[?=]/g, "/");
```

Do note that it's probably better to make a function to **understand** the url structure and rebuild it properly, that will produce a much more healthy, robust code, rather then a simple replacement.

Comment: Double slash does *not* escape a slash.

Comment: My bad, confused with a backslash. Corrected.

Comment: It will work once, but yes, it will fail on the OP's requirements. Fixed. Also, I practically wrote part of that FM, so please, me answering questions when I should be long asleep does not mean I lack in knowledge. http://i.qkme.me/35bp94.jpg << that's the face I made btw :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple string for replace:

```
var ss = "http://localhost/search?search=words".replace("?search=", "/search/");
```